# Using jint to decode Jsfuck

Tags: javascript, c#, jint, jsfuck

I'm trying to use jint to decode jsfuck, and am basing myself off this project: https://github.com/enkhee-Osiris/Decoder-JSFuck (it's the only one I've found that can decode the jsfuck correctly). The following c# isn't working correctly:

```
Jint.Engine engine = new Jint.Engine();
engine.SetValue("code", jsfuck_string);
string result = engine.Execute(@"function decode() {
return (/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(code.value.replace(/\s+/, "").slice(0, -2)))[1]);
}").GetValue("decode").ToString();
```

I'm getting the following exception: `Line 2: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to run the following JavaScript code in Jint:

```
function decode() {
    return (/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(code.value.replace(/\s+/, "").slice(0, -2)))[1]);
}
```

However, `""` in a C# verbatim string (i.e. `@"..."`) represents only a single `"` character.  You're actually trying to run this JS code, which isn't valid as there is an unmatched `"` character:

```
function decode() {
    return (/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(code.value.replace(/\s+/, ").slice(0, -2)))[1]);
}
```

Try replacing the `""` in `replace(/\s+/, "")` in your C# verbatim string with `""""`, or `''`.

Comment: I've taken your advice, and my C# now resembles this: `var result = engine.SetValue("code", data).Execute(@"(/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(code.value.replace(/\s+/, '').slice(0, -2)))[1])").GetCompletionValue();`, but now I'm just getting "Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException" on the entire line :/

Comment: @user2950509: I don't really know what's causing this.  To make matters worse the exception message is rather helpfully empty.  To get any further I think it would be necessary to debug into Jint...